# I am getting this error when I try to click date on calendar widget using selenium

Tags: selenium

I am getting this error when I try to click a date on calendar widget using selenium:

> [JavaScript Error: "b.elementFromPoint is not a function" {file: "file:///tmp/anonymous3738058585112632092webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/synthetic-mouse.js" line: 11130}]'[JavaScript Error: "b.elementFromPoint is not a function" {file: "file:///tmp/anonymous373805858

Comment: provide code used..possible html code or UI where you executed

Answer (score 0):

public void clickOnDate() {

```
    String minDate = "12";
    webDriverWait(2);

    List<WebElement> list = element(test).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
    for(WebElement col : list){
        System.out.println(col.getText());
        if(col.getText().trim().equals(minDate)){

        col.click();
        }
    }

}
```

Here test is containing
By test = By.className("bs-datepicker-body");